# Jenkins Git build branches and tags

Tags: git, jenkins

I'm trying to get jenkins to build on commits to specific branches and any tags that match a pattern. For example, say I have these branches:

master
feature1
release23

I want commits to master and feature* to trigger a build, but not commits to release*. Furthermore, I want to trigger a build whenever there's a tag added that matches the pattern v* (so, v0.1, v1.2, etc.).

I can't seem to get this working. Has anybody tried something similar? What would the refspec, branches to build, etc. be?

Update:

I've tried setting branches to build to

```
**master
**feature**
**/tags/v**
```

It seems that honours branches, but tags to existing commits don't get built.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: There is a "Branches to build" option to use Wildcard (regex) - have you tried this?